# How to evenly space out multiple TextViews in a row in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best way to evenly space out more than 3 TextViews in a row?

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/credits"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/credits" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/status" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the layout_width to 0dp and the `layout_weight=".25"` for each of your textviews then set the left and right margins as necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. :)